# Параметры у функции в JS

Tags: javascript

Передаю в функцию массив параметров. В одном из параметров передается функция, ее вешаю на обработчик событий.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/IVsevolod/d2RKj/)

**Код из примера:**

```
function fun1(param) {
    if (typeof param['button'] !== 'undefined') {
        for (var i =0; i < param['button'].length; i++) {
            var element = param['button'][i];
            if (typeof element['onclick'] !== 'undefined') 
                    $('#test').click(element['onclick']);
        }
    }
}

var p = {};
p['button'] = [{
    'onclick': function() {
        $('#test').html('sdfsdf');
    }
}];

fun1(p);
```

**Как можно передать функцию с параметрами и ее вызвать?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос (надо выполнить функцию из объекта "p" в функции "fun1"), то вот так. Так же можно туда передать и параметры, как при вызове обычной функции.

```
function fun1(param) {
    if (typeof param['button'] !== 'undefined') {
        for (var i =0; i < param['button'].length; i++) {
            var element = param['button'][i];
            if (typeof element['onclick'] !== 'undefined') 
                    element['onclick']();
        }
    }
}

var p = {};
p['button'] = [{
    'onclick': function() {
        $('#test').html('sdfsdf');
    }
}];

fun1(p);
```

Comment: Спасибо :) благодаря ответу понял как можно сделать :)

    $('#test').click(function(){
        element['onclick']();
    });

Просто когда я делал **`$('#test').click(element['onclick']());`** у меня функция вызывалась при инициализации )

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется чище будет возвращать функцию при запросе:

как-то так:

```
//.......
       $('#test').click(element['onclick']('abcdef'))
//.......    
p['button'] = [{
    'onclick': function (param) {
        return function () {
            $('#test').html(param);
        }
    }
}];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d2RKj/1/

Comment: да, думаю будет чище :) спасибо